# umenu.cpp undefined reference error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile a bot, and I've had trouble with it for a few days. After hours of debugging I'm only left with this error:

```
libui.a(libui_a-uMenu.o): In function `uMenuItemString::Event(SDL_Event&) [clone .part.51]':
uMenu.cpp:(.text+0x447c): undefined reference to `get_scrap(int, int*, char**)'
uMenu.cpp:(.text+0x47ac): undefined reference to `init_scrap()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [armagetronad_main] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/noah/0.4-bot/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/noah/0.4-bot/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/noah/0.4-bot'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions `get_scrap()` and `init_scrap()` are missing in your linking. They may be in another source code or library.

Comment: how would i go about finding them

Comment: @puef You will get more info in the link above your question.